# OpenGL - how to draw instances of several objects?

Tags: opengl

I have 3 objects in my scene, each one is being passed to the buffer and drawn as part of a different Vertex Array Object, so for the 3 objects i have:
`vao1`, `vao2`, `vao3`.

`Object1` is drawn using `glDrawElementsInstanced`.

`Object2` is drawn using `glDrawElementsInstanced`.

`Object3` is drawn using `glDrawArraysInstanced`.

All of those instances of all of those objects create one big object. So how can i take that big object (meaning - treat all 3 object as one) and draw it 5 times using instancing?

Thanks!

Comment: at some point you have no choice but to call glDraw* multiple times with different uniforms.

Comment: I don't think that you can treat these 3 objects as one because they belong to different `vaos`. You can't bind more than one `vao` at the time.